# My pydev templates are completely empty and the 'New' button is inoperative. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I recently updated both Eclipse and PyDev to their most recent versions (as of 2021-03).  Most of PyDev is working, but when I open the 'templates' window, there are no entries in the template list.  Further, when I click the 'New' button, nothing happens, so I can't even add one.

I've tried completely removing all eclipse and pydev files I could find, and reinstalling both several times.

I'm guessing that something is missing - either a file containing the templates, or a file for controlling the template function.

At any rate, I use the templates a lot.  Does anyone have any idea what I can do to reenable the templates function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a critical bug in Eclipse (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572634) which made it into 4.19 (2021-03).

It's not only templates which don't work (anything which relies on the internal Jython is broken and other plugins are also affected, not only PyDev).

There are no known workarounds besides using a different version of Eclipse (meaning you can currently use a final release such as 4.18 (2020-12) or you need to get one of the integration builds for 4.20 as it's currently not final).

Comment: Ahhh.   Thank you.  I have another data point, just in case you don't have this one.  In my code listing, are lines starting with a red X but the explainations are in senseless characters.  I'll go back to a previouis build.